# Copy neo4j database from another pc

Tags: neo4j

I did it this way

OVERWRITE DIRECTORY NE04J IN ORIGINAL DOCUMENTS WITH THE EMPTY

- JOIN FOR XP USERNAME / APPLICATION DATA / Neo4j COMMUNITY OR 7 "C: \ Users \ Tuo_Utente \ AppData \ Roaming \ Neo4j COMMUNITY"  COPY THE FOLDER FROM THE ORIGINAL SYSTEM to NEW
- TO JOIN PROGRAMS X86 / NE04J Commuity  COPY THE FOLDER FROM THE ORIGINAL SYSTEM to NEW

I get everything but the web-admin, I have not the various style. how do I import too?

image https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM1MV.png
I have different style with default
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Styling settings are saved with the browser either as cookies or via webbrowser's local storage. So you need to copy that over as well, the exact procedure differs between browser types and versions.

#### amended 2014-09-27

For the the Neo4j browser in the 2.x series (not speaking of 1.x's webadmin):

- install [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) plugin and "[FireStorage Plus!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firestorage-plus/)" plugin.
- open your neo4j browser: `http://localhost:7474`
- press `F12` to open firebug
- go to tab `FireStorage Plus!`
- go to `localStorage`
- `neo4j.grass` contains your UI settings
- `neo4j.documents` contain your saved queries
- use context menu's copy&paste to copy these settings to a file

Comment: Thanks stefan! and how to use this export file  in new machine with "empty" firefox?