# neo4j browser query (not webadmin) not displayed

Tags: neo4j

In Neo4j When I execute a query in  a google crome browser (last version, browser page not webadmin),
often do not I see the results of the query. Then a force of one, two, three .... rerun, it works. 
how so this?
thanks
Luigi

this is some error by devtools : http://s28.postimg.org/5upud8e19/error.jpg

In firefox all work fine!!! Why?

Comment: If you open the DevTools in the Network tab what do you see? Are the requests fired?

Comment: I've got the same errors on a `2.0.3` instance. What version are you using?

Comment: 2.0.3!!!!!!! equal version

Answer (score 0):

Double check if this is happening with the latest Neo4j version (2.1.4 as of today). If the problem persists maybe start of with a fresh browser profile, e.g. by using the `--user-data-dir` command line option. If you still get the error, file a issue at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/new

Comment: OK Thanks. Stefan can you help also in other discussion (Styling setting) ? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26035149/copy-neo4j-database-from-another-pc